# Striping out time components for data in a csv file with | seperated variables

Tags: unix

A bit new to UNIX but I have a question with reagrds altering csv files going into a datafeed.

There are a few | seperated columns where the date has come back as (for example)

|07-04-2006 15:50:33:44:55:66|
and this needs to be changed to
|07-04-2006|

It doesn't matter if all the data gets written to another file. There are thousands of rows in these files.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way of going to the 3rd and 7th piped columns and taking the first 10 characters and removing anything else till the next |

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want?

You can replace `|07-04-2006 15:50:33:44:55:66|` by `|07-04-2006|` using File IO.

Comment: I want to change all the dates in the files to the first 10 characaters after the pipe. Depending of which file it is the positions of the dates may change but thet are consistent within the file.

Comment: Okie. please let us know in which language you want the code?

Comment: It's a LINUX box running Redhat.

Comment: OS is ok but which language you are using? C/C++/Java/php?

Comment: Hi,To to clear up, I want all the data aound the date to remain withing a file and not 'strip out' in the literal sense.

Answer (score 0):

This operates on all columns, but should do unless there are date columns which must not be changed:

```
sed 's/|\(..-..-....\) ..:..:..:..:..:..|/|\1|/g'
```

If you want to change the files in place, you can use sed's `-i` option.